# Entity Framework to json - grouping data

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization

I have a class named **Client** which looks like this:

```
public class Client
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("BaseAssignments")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BaseAssignment> BaseAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

And a class named **Base** looking like this:

```
public class Base
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("BaseAssignments")]
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BaseStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime BaseEnd { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BaseAssignment> BaseAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

They are to be joined with another class called **BaseAssignment**:

```
public class BaseAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int BaseAssignmentId { get; set; }
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Base Base { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that a client can be assigned to many bases, and one base can contain many clients.

Moving forward, I am trying to serialize base entitites in such way that a json representation of a base would have a collection of all it's clients as a subobject. A Web Api method that I'm trying to achieve this is:

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var query = from b in db.Bases
    group b by b.BaseId into nb
    join ba in db.BaseAssignments on nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseId equals ba.BaseId
    join c in db.Clients on ba.ClientId equals c.ClientId
    select new BaseDTO
    {
        BaseName = nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseName,
        BaseStart = nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseStart,
        BaseEnd = nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseEnd,
        Clients = from c1 in db.Clients select new ClientDTO
        {
            ClientId = c1.ClientId,
            CompanyName = c1.CompanyName,
            Owner = c1.Owner
        }
    };
return query;
```

where a **BaseDTO** looks like:

```
public class BaseDTO
{
    public String BaseName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BaseStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime BaseEnd { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<ClientDTO> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

and **ClientDTO** looks like:

```
public class ClientDTO
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

As of now I'm getting an error stating that ClientDTO is an unexpected type. What can I do to fix this, or maybe the way that I've chosen is completely wrong? Thanks in advance for any insight on this.

**EDIT**

I've made some changes to the Web Api controller method, so it looks like:

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var query = from b in db.Bases
    group b by b.BaseId into nb
    join ba in db.BaseAssignments on nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseId equals ba.BaseId
    join c in db.Clients on ba.ClientId equals c.ClientId
    select new BaseDTO
    {
        BaseName = nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseName,
        BaseStart = nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseStart,
        BaseEnd = nb.FirstOrDefault().BaseEnd,
        Clients = new ClientDTO
        {
            ClientId = c.ClientId,
            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
            Owner = c.Owner
        }
    };
return query;
```

This makes the Api produce a JSON, but it still contains a single object for every client, not every base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to group or join anything by hand for this, just use a sub-select and have LINQ to the heavy lifting.

```
from b in db.Bases
select new BaseDTO
{
    BaseName = b.BaseName,
    BaseStart = b.BaseStart,
    BaseEnd = b.BaseEnd,
    Clients = 
        from ba in b.BaseAssignments
        from c in ba.Client
        select new ClientDTO
        {
            ClientId = c.ClientId,
            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
            Owner = c.Owner
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that one. Still, I had to change the navigation property in BaseAssignments from Client to IQueryable<Client>, and now the product JSON's "Clients" object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [StriplingWarrior's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120955/striplingwarrior) suggestion, mixing best of both worlds into:

```
from b in db.Bases
select new BaseDTO
{
    BaseName = b.BaseName,
    BaseStart = b.BaseStart,
    BaseEnd = b.BaseEnd,
    Clients =
        from ba in b.BaseAssignments 
        join c in db.Clients on ba.ClientId equals c.ClientId
        select new ClientDTO
        {
            ClientId = c.ClientId,
            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
            Owner = c.Owner
        }
 };
```

got the JSON I wanted - thanks.